# What is the Difference between Client Side & Server Side Rendering?

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, server-side

Ok, I've been working on a Node Js course & I'm a bit confused as of what is the difference between client side & server side rendering.

1st Question: What is the purpose of using front end in the client side WHEN you can just serve up HTML/CSS Through the server side back-end by using app.use(express.static(__dirname, 'public')? from my understanding it accomplishes the same thing.

2 Question: What is the purpose of front-end if you can just accomplish the same thing by using app.get() on an express server.

I'm really confused on front-end and back end and when it is appropriate to use front end/ express.static() OR just serving up files on the express server. Please explain your answer in the easiest way and not a bunch of tech jargon.

Comment: yeah but what you are Serving through app.use or app.get IS THE FRONT END CODE!

Answer (score 2):

This is a question that implies opinionated answers, which is not the purpose of StackOverflow. I'll still provide an answer with factual arguments.

The pros of client-side rendering over server-side rendering is that it improves user experience by never reloading the page. The network usage is reduced to a minimum (only data to display, in JSON which is a very light format) which makes it faster overall. You can also do things like animate navigations, etc...

On the other side, it takes more time to start because of the size of the JS files (often several MB), and it's less SEO-friendly (Google has improved on this  since they no longer use Chrome 41 for their GoogleBot, but it still doesn't index client-side rendered sites very well).

Most JavaScript frameworks abstract DOM manipulations, and allow client-side to get along with server-side, since JavaScript can execute in browsers and in Node.js. This allows to benefit from the best of both worlds.